# What firewall settings should be updated in order to connect mysql to google compute engine

Tags: java, mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have created a compute engine instance and have installed MySQL also authorized to cloud sql instance. Need to change some firewall settings to open port 3306 used this command:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create FIREWALL_RULE --allow tcp:3306
```

But still not able to connect to database. I am getting the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: by issuing this command you are opening the 3306 port on the default network. Is your instance running on the default network or on a different one? Another thing to check is also the iptables on the instance. Try disabling the iptables to test. In the authorized network also you need to authorize the public IP of your instance not the private one.

Comment: Check that Mysql is listening on all addresses and not only locally. In /etc/mysql/my.cnf (for Debian OS) check : bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Comment: i tried using  bind-address = 0.0.0.0 and  bind-address = localhost, also it did not work for me, getting this error ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) while writing this command on ssl: mysql --host=localhost --user=<username> --password

Answer (score 0):

test by switching off iptables by running following command:

```
    sudo service iptables stop
```

If that works then, restart iptables & allow 3306 port (mysql port) by:

```
    sudo service iptables restart
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
    sudo service iptables save
```

> ** the above commands are for linux OS

Comment: still getting com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: should i need to change bindaddress too? it is mentioned 127.0.0.1

Comment: yes change it to:  `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`      , so that it can listen on all IP,
also you can check mysql is accepting connections by running:  `telnet localhost 3306`

Comment: do i need to overwrite in /etc/my.cnf, i am using centos, and have no permission to run telnet command

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
 (2) while writing this command on ssl: mysql --host=localhost --user=<username> --password

Comment: try  `sudo telnet localhost 3306`  to check if mysql is running and accepting connections

Comment: while giving this command `sudo service mysql start` getting `mysql: unrecognized service`

Comment: Try starting it using this command:  sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start